# How to delete Range in Aspose(using C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, aspose, aspose-cells

I am trying to remove the range through aspose but no luck. Actually i have created a range in excel but while exporting the excel when there is no data to insert into the excel and when we select the range it always select the empty rows. So i want to update the range to the header only or first delete the range and then again adding that.
Please suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may use any of the NameCollection.Remove or RemoveAt methods to remove a particular Named Range from the collection. Please review the following piece of code as well as the [details article on Named Ranges](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsnet/Named+Ranges) in prespective of Aspose.Cells for .NET APIs.

```
    var book = new Workbook(dir + "book1.xlsx");
    var names = book.Worksheets.Names;
    names.Remove("range");
```

In case you still face any difficulty, please share your sample spreadsheet in [Aspose.Cells support forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.cells-product-family/19/showforum.aspx).

Note: I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.